# Can node.js be selectively introduced into a web application built in vanilla PHP/JS/CSS/HTML?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, sockets, websocket

I have very little knowledge of node.js,

Let's say we have a web application built with vanilla php/js/css/html...

By "selectively", I mean being able to have, for instance, the notification part of a page being managed by node.js, with the rest of the page remaining vanilla.

We lack a websocket/real time communication channel - I would prefer to set up an effective/actual real time communication channel instead of some sort of long-polling method/timed ajax refresh loop/adhoc solution.

I am looking at socket.io and as far as I understand, this requires node.js, would this be able to be integrated into an existing application? If so, where would I start?

I am open to suggestions for other real time communication channels in node.js as well as any other real time communication channel that may be compatible with PHP/vanilla JS.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please note that this is a question and answer site, not a
code writing service. If you [edit] your question to
describe what you have tried so far and where you are stuck,
then we can try to help with specific problems. You should
also read [ask].

Comment: @TobySpeight If you had taken the time to read my *question*, you may have noticed that I did not request any code to be written, I am still awaiting an *answer*. Thanks :)

Comment: "Where do I start?" is still too broad to be a good Stack Overflow question.

Comment: @TobySpeight However, Shilly provided me with a good Stack Overflow answer. :)

Comment: Since you ask for suggestions on possible real-time frameworks, you should check out Lightstreamer (lightstreamer.com), which integrates very well with a vanilla web app. You can definitely selectively introduce real-time features without altering your web app, as Lightstreamer Server sits along your existing web server. [Full disclosure: I am the CTO of Lightstreamer]

Answer (score 1):

Node.js is a javascript runtime working on the server side (like PHP). I don't see any reason why you shouldn't be able to introduce it for websocket communitaction.

So shortly saying yes you can use it.

Comment: Yes. Install node.js and npm (node packet manager) on your server. Install the modules needed to use socket.io. Then create a socket connection in the client code that will relay all the incoming messages to the functions you use to handle notifications. Then on the node server, set up a script that accepts socket connections and that will send messages over the socket every time a notification is detected on the server.

Comment: @Shilly Thank you, I love you!